# How to disable fast touches and double opening view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Please help me with problem -
I have button, or label, or textfield at UiViewController view, which have method to open another view, if i touch it.

But if i touch button, label or textfield very fast, it can open two, or three, or more same views.

How to disable this opening? How to open only one view?
How i can do this for all project?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use something like a boolean that indicates that another view is opening/open?

Comment: @Liminic, i think it must be universal method to do this

Comment: Define "open a view". On iOS, all the UI interaction happens on the UI main thread. If you tap a button, it will call a selector or execute a block to navigate to a new page or something like this. This also is scheduled on the UI main loop. Unless you interact on the UI from another thread (which will not work), I don't see how you could possible double-tap a button*. (*This applies to standard UI interaction. Situation is different if tapping the button triggers an async event which will eventually "open the view")

Answer (score 1):

when you click on button then Calling method of the Button, Inside the button method you disable your button, and after when you dismiss open view then again you enable your button.

```
-(void)YourButtonMethod
{
  YourBtn.enable = false;
}
```

// Enable your `YourBtn` when dismiss yourView.

Comment: May be, but i need do this in all buttons, labels and etc. in project. It make copy-paste. i need method for all project.

Comment: yes, you have to put it in all to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to disable the `UIButton` when you enter the function and re-enable it before leaving. Would look something like this function

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)aButton
{
   aButton.enabled = false;
// do your work here
// and before leaving

aButton.enabled = true;
}
```

But in your case you are pushing a `UIViewController`, so you should move the line `aButton.enabled = true` to your `prepareForSegue` function.